# Form 1 detects if Form 2 closes C#

Tags: c#

Ive actually searched for this and i dont understand a thing. I even tried coding this but im still confused. How will Form1 detects if Form2 closes? I dont get how the Formclose event works and linking it to Form1. I was hoping someone will clarify this

Comment: Is this in winforms? Show us what you have tried so far so that we can get some context

Comment: you´lle need to register an event-handler to the event, something like `frm2.Close += myInstanceOfForm1.DoSomething;` where `DoSomething` is a method expecting `(object sender, EventArgs args)`.

Comment: In form one. I'll press a button that will show `Form2` as a dialog. In form 2 there's nothing in it except for another button the will close that form. Now what im trying to do is show a messagebox once Form2 closes

Comment: If it is a modal dialog execution of form will will *pause* as long as form2 is open. So simply add your logic after the `ShowDialog`-call.

Comment: Aye, if you use form2.ShowDialog() rather than form2.Show(), then the execution of that piece of code in form1. stops at ShowDialog, until that dialog closes. Then you can display that messagebox on the next line after that.

Comment: Ohhhh! so for instance. IF form2 closes as a dialog it will run whatever is next the ShowDialog()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your are opening Form2 from inside Form1 you can subscribe to the Form2 closing event inside Form1 (I'm not 100% sure how this works)
Pseudo-code:

- Start Form2 inside Form1 using ***Form2.Show***
- Form2.OnClosing (or Form2.OnClosed) += *Form2ClosedEventHandler*

Create function inside **Form1**:

- *Form2ClosedEventHandler*
- Do your work here.

If you don't want to work with EventHandlers, you could open ***Form2.ShowDialog*** instead of ***Form2.Show***, from **Form1**. 
Any code you put after ***Form2.ShowDialog*** will run after **Form**2 has closed.